# Как сделать так, чтобы контроллер сам выбирал класс который подходит по параметрам в json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

В заголовке не совсем понятно объяснил, но я не смог скомпоновать проблему в одну строчку)
Есть один метод в контроллере, который в себя принимает некоторый Response, который содержит поля type и object. Запросы отправляемые в этот меняются в зависимости от type. Допустим

```
{
"type":"info",
"object": {
    "id": "111",
    "name": "111"
    }
}
```

Другой type, например не info, а message будет содержать допустим user_id, message. Как мне формировать класс? Просто закидать туда все возможные варианты запроса?

```
public class Response
{
    public string type {get; set;}
    [JsonPropertyName("object")]
    public Object Object { get; set; }
}
public class Object
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string user_name {get; set;}
    public string message {get; set;}
}
```

По-моему это странно. Если будет много параметров то класс будет очень большим и можно легко запутаться в нем. И выглядит не красиво. Хочется видеть интерфейс response и классы message, info (те что в type), но это не работает так как я хочу. Сделать так, чтобы message прокидывался на отдельный метод TestForMessage я не могу. Все должно идти в один общий метод.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public IActionResult Test([FromBody] Response response)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Вам не кажется, что раз вы полезли в такие дебри, то стоит уже использовать что-то готовое для этого? Например, GraphQL...

Comment: Это ASP.NET Core или ASP.NET? Можете без десереализации посмотреть, что там за строчка, например `Utf8JsonReader`, либо десереализовать в класс, в котором вообще нет свойства `objrct`, а потом уже передать в полную десерализацию. Например с использованием Generic класса для модели. Принимайте запрос как `string`, а не как Json, и десереализуйте руками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если трудно натянуть данные на конкретную модель, можно использовать JToken:

```html
JToken responseObject = JToken.Parse(response);
if(responseObject.Value<string>("type") == "message"){

}
```

или

```html
switch (responseObject.Value<string>("type"))
      {
          case 1:
              Console.WriteLine("info");
              break;
          case 2:
              Console.WriteLine("message");
              break;
          default:
              Console.WriteLine("Default case");
              break;
      }
```